# Navegar En La Web En Una App De Consola

Tags: c#

Yo intento crear un objeto Web Browser desde una aplicación de Consola, aquí lo que intento hacer pero me produce un error:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();

        web.Navigate("www.es.stackoverflow.com");

        Console.WriteLine("Funcionando Correctamente");
    }
```

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' en System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: ¿Qué quieres hacer exactamente?

Comment: Quiero crear un objecto WebBrowser

Comment: A ver, la cuestión es que Windows Forms es para programar interfaz gráfica, y una aplicación de consola... pues no tiene interfaz gráfica (igual puedes lanzar una desde allí, pero no la tiene por defecto). Así que no está muy claro qué quieres hacer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebBrowser` es parte de Windows forms por lo cual no deberías usarla en una aplicación de consola si quieres "navegar en la web desde la consola" usa `Net`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://es.stackoverflow.com/");
            System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```